# TextFSM - Parsing Issues

Tags: python-textfsm

I have some trouble with textFSM, and I don't know if I am doing it right:

So the output that i want to parse is this one:

```
snmp-server host 10.140.300.200 traps version 2c ldldo-1ldd
snmp-server host 10.140.300.200 use-vrf management
snmp-server host 10.132.300.101 traps version 2c oelee-doeoel
snmp-server host 10.132.300.101 use-vrf management
snmp-server host 10.132.300.101 source-interface kedl1
snmp-server host 10.151.230.230 traps version 2c SNMP1sAPain
snmp-server host 10.105.10.104 traps version 2c oelee-doeoel
snmp-server host 10.105.10.104 use-vrf management
snmp-server host 10.105.10.104 source-interface kedl1
```

And my template is:

```
Value host (\S+)
Value version (\S+)
Value community (\S+)
Value vrf (\S+)
Value source_interface (\S+)

Start
  ^snmp-server\s+host\s+${host}\s+traps\s+version\s+${version}\s+${community}
  ^snmp-server\s+host\s+${host}\s+use-vrf\s+${vrf}
  ^snmp-server\s+host\s+${host}\s+source-interface\s+${source_interface} -> Record
```

the output:

```
[{'host': '10.132.300.101',
  'version': '2c',
  'community': 'oelee-doeoel',
  'vrf': 'management',
  'source_interface': 'kedl1'},
 {'host': '10.105.10.104',
  'version': '2c',
  'community': 'oelee-doeoel',
  'vrf': 'management',
  'source_interface': 'kedl1'}
```

But with that template I only capture the output which mirror that.

How can I capture the others hosts: '10.140.300.200', '10.151.230.230'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You see the problem, right?  Your template requires all 3 lines, but the other two IPs don't have all 3 lines.

Honestly, do you really need a package?  This file would be very easy to parse just by doing `line.split()`.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Thanks for your answer, but this is a part of an output running config from switch, which i am parsing with blocks of templates, to work with text like these textfsm do the job almost. Can you help me how can i get the other values without 'damage' what is collected?

Comment: You may be able to include alternative blocks that match just traps and use-vrf, or just traps.  https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/21_textfsm/textfsm_examples.html#show-ip-route-ospf

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution without requiring any external modules:

```
import json

lastip = None
collection = []
for line in open('x.txt'):
    parts = line.rstrip().split()[2:]
    ip = parts.pop(0)
    verb = parts.pop(0)
    if ip != lastip:
        collection.append( {'host': ip} )
        lastip = ip
    if verb == 'traps':
        collection[-1]['version'] = parts[1]
        collection[-1]['community'] = parts[2]
    elif verb == 'use-vrf':
        collection[-1]['vrf'] = parts[0]
    elif verb == 'source-interface':
        collection[-1]['source_interface'] = parts[0]

print(json.dumps(collection,indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "host": "10.140.300.200",
        "version": "2c",
        "community": "ldldo-1ldd",
        "vrf": "management"
    },
    {
        "host": "10.132.300.101",
        "version": "2c",
        "community": "oelee-doeoel",
        "vrf": "management",
        "source_interface": "kedl1"
    },
    {
        "host": "10.151.230.230",
        "version": "2c",
        "community": "SNMP1sAPain"
    },
    {
        "host": "10.105.10.104",
        "version": "2c",
        "community": "oelee-doeoel",
        "vrf": "management",
        "source_interface": "kedl1"
    }
]
```